# finding addressof a object whose ampersand operator is overloaded and private

Tags: c++

I have a class which is overloading ampersand(&) operator and made it private. I don't have a latest C++11 compliant compiler so is there any way by which I can get address of my object using current C++ compiler only

Thanks

Comment: If you have control over object definition, use `new` and get the address of the object from the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`addressof()`](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof) function from Boost.Utility. If you don't want to use Boost, you can still look at it's [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/utility/addressof.hpp) which consists of just a single header.

Answer (score 2):

```
reinterpret_cast<T *>(&reinterpret_cast<char&>(obj))
```

Dunno if it's safe though.. (well clearly it's a bit dodgy)

Comment: It’s not at all dodgy, it just doesn’t take into account cv-qualification. Also, the outer cast could be a `static_cast`.

Comment: That's what Boost does too (with the addition of a `const volatile` to the `char&` type).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I prefer reinterpret_cast for this

Comment: @NeilKirk It’s not really a matter of preference. You should always choose the least powerful cast possible to strengthen type safety and avoid errors. Using `reinterpret_cast` circumvents most of the type system and is an inherently unsafe action, which should therefore be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think static_cast would even compile.

Comment: @Neil You’re right of course. My mistake – I was thinking of `void*`, not `char*`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but 2 `static_casts`s could do it instead of 1 `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @user1095108 This is where I prefer to use reinterpret_cast instead of chains of static_casts. It's a bit dodgy, so the code should appear as such.

Comment: @user1095108 No, that’s illegal because it violates aliasing rules. When casting to `void*`, the only legal cast is back to the same type, not to any other type.